# Convex Optimization for Matlab

Tags: matlab, mathematical-optimization, convex-optimization

I want to know how can i solve the following minimization problem with matlab:

> > A is a semi-positive definite matrix. (All eigenvalues are greater or iqual than 0)
> >     F=F(x_1,...,x_n,y_1,y_2) = (F_1,...,F_2n) is a linear function.
> >
> > i want to find (x_1,...,x_n,y_1,y_2)
> >     so that:
> >
> > F*A*F' is minimum.
> >     There are no restriction in the variables, but notice that there are substantially less than the vector length.

I am trying to minicime a statistical distance. I can't find on the web what functions to use.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this homework? What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: No. It's not homework. And there is nothing to try. I was just asking if anyone new a matlab solver for my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for unconstrained optimization in MATLAB you can use `fminunc`. To do so, you can define your cost function:

```
function z = costfun(x)
f = F*A*F';    % where F is a function of x=[x_1,...y_n]
```

then call `fminunc` to find the minimum. Vector `x0` is provided as a starting point for searching.

```
[x,zval] = fminunc(@costfun,x0);
```

Comment: Thanks @ramino. It's an interesting function i wasn't aware of. Anyway I found a specific function for my problem.                   x = quadprog(H,f,A,b,Aeq,beq). The problem it can actually be formulated as a quadratic programming.